# vb.net arcobjects enable customized context menu item only if a feature is selected

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, vb.net, context-menu

The solution may be very simple, but I haven't made it work.

I want to enable a data view context menu item only if a feature (in polyline layer) is selected, all other places the item should in grey. May I say what I need to do is check whether a feature is selected? I searched for this but don't find a proper solution. Or any other concerns?

I am using ArcObjects 10.2.2 and VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making an ArcGIS Add-In (rather than the old extension format), then I believe you can enable / disable buttons or menu items inside your button class like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
    Enabled = bSelected
End Sub
```

Where bSelected is your boolean indicating whether or not your feature is selected. You can check if a feature in a particular featurelayer is selected like this:

```
Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection = pLayer
If pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count = 0 Then
   bSelected = False
Else
   bSelected = True
End If
```

Or you could put them together to cut down on code. Try this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
   Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection = pLayer
   If pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count = 0 Then
      Enabled = False
   Else
      Enabled= True
   End If 
End Sub
```

EDIT: I've just realised you said context-menu, which I assume means a right click menu? In which case I'm not sure as I've never used context menus in ArcMap.

Comment: may be a better option to only update `bSelected` in response to events in `ISelectionEvents Interface` so that you're only checking the selection count when it actually changes, and not every time ArcGIS fires the update event